# optimize an active record query omitting nil fields on associated record

Tags: ruby, activerecord, orm, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to select all records from a model besides the records which have nil fields in an associated record. So far I have this:

```
User.where("id NOT IN (?)", User.all(:include => :profile, :conditions => {:profiles => {:first_name => nil, :last_name => nil}}))
```

I'm wondering if there is a more direct or optimal way to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

User.includes(:profile).where('profiles.first_name IS NOT ? AND profiles.last_name IS NOT ?', nil, nil)

**Update**: Replaced != with IS NOT. The operator != is not allowed in sql. It should be working now.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. No records return with that query but I get a few with the one I posted. Not sure why though. Seems like it should work.